# Range in elasticsearch not really working

Tags: elasticsearch

I run this query:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/mydocs/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { 
    "bool" : { "must" : [{"wildcard": {"guid": "14744*"}}, {"range": {"availability.start": {"lt": "now"}}}] }
  }
}
'
```

I then get this response:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "mydocs",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "14744",
    "_score" : 2.0,
    "_source" : {
      "guid" : "14744",
      "availability" : {
        "start" : "2021-03-28T22:00:00.000Z",
        "end" : "2021-12-31T22:59:00.000Z"
      },
      "title" : "Some title"
    }
  }
]
```

What I actually want is results where today is in the range for the availability's start and end.
The above results says the document is available between

```
2021-03-28T22:00:00.000Z
and
2021-12-31T22:59:00.000Z
```

Today is 2021-04-15:15:00.000Z

So, what I shoud do is to add:

```
{"range": {"availability.end": {"gt": "now"}}}
```

isn't it correct? But when I run:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/mydocs/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { 
    "bool" : { "must" : [{"wildcard": {"guid": "14744*"}}, {"range": {"availability.start": {"lt": "now"}}}, {"range": {"availability.end": {"gt": "now"}}}] }
  }
}
'
```

I got an empty hits list.

Partial mapping:

```
{
mappings: {
    _doc: {
        properties: {
            availability: {
                properties: {
                    end: {
                        type: "keyword"
                    },
                    start: {
                        type: "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
        properties: {
            guid: {
                type: "keyword"
            }
        }
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index?

Comment: Running your query, I get the document OK.

Comment: Mapping is quite big and there are reference to other system's functions. However, the first part that involves the requested fields has been added to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is perfectly correct! Good job with that!

The problem is that the `availability.*` fields are defined as `keyword`.

They MUST be of type `date` in order for `range` queries on date values to deliver accurate results, otherwise the range queries will just perform a lexical (i.e. string) comparison of `now` vs the date values expressed as strings:

```
        availability: {
            properties: {
                end: {
                    type: "date"        <--- change this
                },
                start: {
                    type: "date"        <--- and this
                }
            }
        },
```

You can't change the mapping of existing fields, but you can always create new fields. So, you can change your mapping to create new `date` sub-fields for both `start` and `end`, like this:

```
PUT mydocs/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "availability": {
      "properties": {
        "end": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "date": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        },
        "start": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "date": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you simply need to run the following command in order to update your index:

```
POST mydocs/_update_by_query
```

And then modify your query to use the new sub-fields and that will work:

```
POST mydocs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "guid": "14744*"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "availability.start.date": {
              "lt": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "availability.end.date": {
              "gt": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. IN a situation where it is not that easy to modify mapping: is there a workaround to transform the field to date type on the fly or stuff like that?